# Webpack babel parser breaks on < with a npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I installed this [npm module](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-accordion) and upon `npm start`, it gives me

```js
ERROR in ./~/react-native-accordion/src/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users...\node_modules\react-native-accordion\src\index.js Line 95: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     return (
|       /*jshint ignore:start */
|       <View
|         style={{
|           overflow: 'hidden'
 @ ./~/react-native-accordion/index.ios.js 1:17-39
```

Until this module, my webpack.config.js has survived all other stuff thrown at it. From reading around, apparentely it's not meant to be parsing node_modules anyway since they're only expected to conform to ES5, so I tried excluding the modules path with

```js
  exclude: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
  ],
```

but to no avail. Here's my complete webpack.config.js:

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.scss', '.js', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
    ]
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ],
  exclude: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules"),
  ],
  module: {
    noParse: /node_modules\/json-schema\/lib\/validate\.js/,
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap!toolbox')
      },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
      { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-loader?pngScale=2' }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [autoprefixer]
};
```

Comment: There may be a few problems here. First, you do want to parse the react-native-accordion module, since it includes React syntax, as you can see if your look at the source code. Second, I am not that familiar with React Native, but I am pretty sure it requires a different configuration than plain old React. The first problem is easy to fix, but if that doesn't fix it, I'm afraid I couldn't tell you exactly how to address the second. If no one else can, you might start [here](https://github.com/jhabdas/react-native-webpack-starter-kit/blob/master/webpack.config.js).

Comment: I didn't realise React Native was a separate thing which wasn't compatible with plain old React. I'll probably not use this module then, thanks for the info.